# Can $_SERVER be faked in PHP?

Tags: php, security, file, server-side-includes

In PHP, Remote file inclusion can be conducted via input from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`. I know it is improbable, but is it possible (by any chance) to fake the value come out of `$_SERVER`?

I mean, can `$_SERVER` become the source of Remote file inclusion even on rare occasion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which $_SERVER variables are safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_SERVER is an array containing information on paths used to access the request, headers etc.

A number of the values are directly set and manipulated by the user (such as QUERY_STRING) so it is potentially vulnerable in exactly the same way as $_GET and $_POST. That depends on how you use those values in your own code though.

Did you have a specific index of $_SERVER in mind that you wouldn't want faking?

Comment: My focus is on server definition values such as DOCUMENT_ROOT, SERVER_NAME, PHP_SELF, etc. These can be used to locate a local php file for `include`.

Comment: PHP_SELF is certainly not to be trusted. try creating a file echoing it and requesting it like so.   "domain.com/phpselfecho.php/anyrandompieceoftext". It's much better to use SCRIPT_NAME

Comment: @Nick Downton: but that's a XSS vulnerability

Comment: Yes, in that instance, but it's certainly worth highlighting. I also don't think it is immediately obvious where that value is obtained from i.e. the user's input. If you really are using php_self in an include(), then the user potentially has the opportunity to alter what you are including.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to manipulate some of the values in $_SERVER.

However an LFI relies on the attacker being able to inject a reference to the code to be executed *and* get PHP to execute that code. Unless you intend to ignore everything other than the URL sent in every request (i.e. you are running a static site) then you'll get a lot more mileage out of focussing your efforts on how code referenced by a variable is being invoked.