# Can I trust the contents of the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable?

Tags: php, security

I am using wildcard subdomains to give each of our users a page username.domain.com.

The usernames themselves are properly sanitized on signup.

To simplify things for the purposes of this question, assume I have a single PHP script that runs for all requests. It gets the domain components using...

```
$domain_components = explode( '.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
```

... and then pops off the tld, the primary domain and the subdomain.

The question is, do I need to treat the contents of the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variable, and in particular the domain components, as potentially hostile? Intuitively, I would think not since PHP and Apache must be doing as good a job as I could do before this ever reaches my code (and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474936/123749) seems to confirm it since the variable is under server control), but I would like to be sure that I'm not overlooking anything.

Do you know of any known attacks via `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`?

(I'm using PHP 5.3.9 and Apache 2.2.3.)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the `$_SERVER` variables are constructed by the server - and therefore the external browsers cannot affect its contents unless your server is compromised. If that is the case, the contents of $_SERVER is the least of your worries.

**EDIT**

I was meant to add except those that take the form `$_SERVER['HTTP...]`.

Comment: Most of them are. Remember that things like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` are changeable by the client.

Comment: Thanks. As ceejayoz points out, this is not the case for many $_SERVER variables that are under client control. The answer I linked to in the question lays this out quite nicely. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6474936/123749

Answer (score 0):

http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

There seem to be some risks, there are some hints in that post although it is old. It might not be wrong to just use that variable (sanitized/escaped!) in a query to find the right user and if that works accept it. After that point you don't need it anymore so just use only your internal data.

Answer (score -1):

You can trust `SERVER_NAME` it sets by:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName server.domain.com
ServerAlias server server2.domain.com server2
# ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is only true when use when usecanonicalname is on.