# how safe is $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]?

Tags: php, superglobals

I have a database full of website urls, the primary key is the `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` of the website.

When a user navigates to ... lets say `www.my-epic-example-url.com`, It will connect the the database and use the `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` of that websites, then fetches all the data referencing that website!

What I want to know is, how safe is `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` ?

Can it be externally modified?

The only reason i ask is because i read an artical a while back ( cant remember where it was ) saying be careful when using $_SERVER because it is unsafe...

Is this true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which $_SERVER variables are safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe)

Comment: Please don't close this as dupe, it's now a circular reference since I am linking from [Which $_SERVER variables are safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe) to here for a detailed explanation of `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between HTTP\_HOST and SERVER\_NAME in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297403/what-is-the-difference-between-http-host-and-server-name-in-php)

Answer (score 20):

`$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` is the HTTP `Host` header, as sent from the client. That makes this header generally *unsafe*.

But, if you are in a typical virtual host setup in which the web server decides which script to execute based on VirtualHost configurations, which in turn are triggered by the HTTP `Host` header, your script *should* not get executed unless a known, whitelisted value was received in that header.

If the web server does not care about the `Host` header and executes a certain script for any and all requests, then this value could be absolutely anything.

Comment: You ought to add some of this into your comprehensive answer on the dupe. You don't specifically explain the VirtualHost part there.

Comment: Done, referred to this answer from the other. :)

Comment: Note that they are known ways of bypassing the VirtualHost restriction, like using absolute URI in the HTTP request, this leads to a free-to-play Host header. So the *generally unsafe* is very true.