# Safely get the URL using $_SERVER

Tags: php, security, url

I'm creating a web app that has many domains pointing to the same app, but the content displayed will depend on the domain used to reach the app.

I am currently using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

to get the the domain and pull in the correct content.

I read this is not safe, because

> The client can set HTTP_HOST to any arbitrary value it wants

from [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

How is this possible and how can I protect against this?

Comment: It is safe if you configure virtual hosts in a way to make sure your php is served from and only from known hostname http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350602/how-safe-is-serverhttp-host/10350718#10350718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTTP_HOST in a comparison statement such as IF is perfectly fine. You would only start to run into problems if you use the HTTP_HOST data directly into a method which requires sanitized data such as a SQL query string, as the user could malform the header to perform SQL Injection

If the user malforms the host header, and you have an IF comparison such as if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.google.com') then changing it would not do anything useful for a malicious user. If you controlled the context through that header, then it would simply not print anything

[See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe#answer-6474936)

Comment: I think the concern here is more about the authenticity of the HTTP_HOST value rather than trying to inject code.

Comment: Indeed it can be spoofed by the user, if it's simply a matter of redirecting the user to appropriate content then it should be fine. If you used it as a switch statement, it would probably refuse to serve anything or serve the contents of another site, much the same as actually visiting the other site

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only use the host to determine which content to use so that's fine

Answer (score 1):

HTTP_HOST comes from the raw HTTP request. Such a request may look like:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

The host field is especially useful when a single IP address serves multiple sites, it is a way of saying *"hello server, out of all websites you may host, I'd like to view this particular one."* Depending on how your server is configured (e.g., Apache's virtualhost), it may accept arbitrary values and serve a default website, or use a white-list and reject non white-listed values.

Either way, in your PHP code you should validate if the HTTP_HOST value is something you expect. If it is not, you should serve a HTTP error page, such as `403 permission denied`. It makes no sense to rely on a server configuration to white-list values.