# Using PHP to generate internal links

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode, internal-link

I'm using a localhost site as the basis for creating other sites from. I'm using php to generate internal links by finding the current domain, and displaying it with a shortcode.  I intend to upload my site to a live host and therefore the domain will change, and my internal links won't be broken.

```
//add shortcode that displays current site name
function GR_site_name(){
$currentDomain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
return $currentDomain.'/wordpress';
}

add_shortcode('GR_site_name', 'GR_site_name');
?>
```

I've tested this by adding the code to live sites and it works perfectly.

I've read the post at [how safe is $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350602/how-safe-is-serverhttp-host) however it details it as 'generally unsafe' due to the script that it runs.

Is $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] safer than $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']? Or are both regarded as bad practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how safe is $\_SERVER\["HTTP\_HOST"\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350602/how-safe-is-serverhttp-host)

Answer (score 0):

Make a config file with define('host','https://example.com') and use host wherever you want and when you upload script to server just change url in config file and you're good to go

Comment: We can't trust anything that comes from client! Hope it solves your problem and in case if it still persists feel free to ask

Comment: I've added  define('host','https://example.com'); to my config file but the shortcode is still returning the same value, meaning it will still use the value defined by client.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Managed to work it out, was defining too early.
 
I've added $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='example.com';

underneath

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress');

and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the standard `WP_HOME` & `WP_SITEURL` constants, along with the `site_url()` function.

I'd recommend using one local copy of `wp-config.php` and a different one for the live site, and then add the following to them:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/wordpress');   // Or 'http://localhost/wordpress' for the local copy
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com');
```

That way, you don't need a custom function or shortcode - you can simply call `site_url()` wherever you need it to get the URL of your WP site.

Alternatively, if you need to keep the site URL variable and to accept anything that points to it:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wordpress');
```

If you need to keep the shortcode for use within the context of a post, you can change it to:

```
function GR_site_name(){
    return site_url();
}
```

Note that setting `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` override any database setting for the site's URL, and if you visit the `Settings->General` page, you'll see those two fields are greyed out.