# Is there a good alternative to $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?

Tags: php, apache, security, superglobals

I read the following comment on [PHP doc pages](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> "Be warned that most contents of the Server-Array (even
>   $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) are provided by the client and can be
>   manipulated. They can also be used for injections and thus MUST be
>   checked and treated like any other user input."

An then I saw a topic here [on StackOverflow saying that $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is partly server controlled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe/6474936#6474936).

Can I trust on this value to get the url of my website? If I can't really trust $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], how can I get this value? What are some possible alternatives and their pro and cons?

**OBS:** *PHP 5.3 on Apache, Unix.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this variable's safety by enabling the UseCanonicalName directive inside your Apache configuration, as described there http://www.apacheref.com/ref/http_core/UseCanonicalName.html

Answer (score 3):

I usually hardcode the 'real' url to my website into a site configuration file.  I wouldn't rely on what Apache 'says' to tell you your url. Do you have several different vhost or server aliases pointing to the same docroot?

Comment: Actually, I'm also hardcoding it until now. Just wondering if there is a more efficient way. But it's good to know that is a practice.