# Loading view inside view, how to get name of main view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, path, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have created a view **main.php** and I have loaded the view **internal.php** inside **main.php**

Now, using the following code inside **internal.php**:

```
pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '.php'
```

or the code:

```
echo $_ci_view;
```

i am getting **internal.php** while I want **main.php** as it is the main view being loaded in browser window.
How can I do this?

Comment: Is the url in your browser changing when loading internal.php?

Comment: No, i am getting main in url

Comment: But since I am using the page name fetching code inside internal, thats why it is showing internal. But how to show main there?

Comment: Why do you need this information?

Comment: Also, I cannot write the page view name fetching code inside main page because internal page has a form which is submitted and inside controller, I am receiving the view name from posted data of this form.

Comment: What I am doing is... internal form is being loaded in several outer views. on submitting form, I need to come back to the view from where form was posted. So, on posting form, I am taking view name to controller, doing code work and loading the main view again.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data

Answer (score 1):

you can parse the url like this:

```
$q=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$q=(isset($q['path']))?$q['path']:'';
```

`echo $q` outputs e.g.: '/main.php'

see more at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and about [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: What is $query here? my page name is main.php so url looks like: abc.com/main

Comment: parse_url returns an array

Comment: as you need the path and not the query part, I've updated the answer

Comment: will it have any adverse effect on security or performance in codeigniter?

Comment: and the url still shows the name of controller instead of showing the name of view ... how this can be rectified?

Comment: also Deceze wrote a very interesting post on that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474936/2275490

Comment: U didnot get it. My query is that the form from main view calls controller sendmessage. Then in sendmessage, I loaded view main, but the url still says servername/sendmessage even after loading view. How to show servername/main here?

Answer (score 0):

use 
include 'location/filename.php';
inside main.php

ref https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_include2

Comment: does it adversly effect the security part or performance aspect of codeigniter in any manner?

Comment: loading a single file(contain everything) and loading a file with in another file definitely have Performance difference ,but that difference less

Comment: Actually there is no security issues, but checking the file whether it is exist or not before loading is always good