# change $_SERVER variables in client-side

Tags: php, security

according to [this site](http://www.patpohler.com/codeigniter-multiple-environments/) $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] can be changed by client.
is it really possible? if yes, how?
and can client change other parameters of $_SERVER?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459739/php-serverhttp-host-vs-serverserver-name-am-i-understanding-the-ma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP request headers are sent by the client and so are determined by the client, so of course it can, as can any other HTTP request header.

Naturally, this is with the proviso that the HTTP server may make use of the Host header and thus decide the request was intended for a different virtual name host and not run the PHP script at all.

Comment: how can I see if my HTTP server(Apache) reject fake requests?

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer very useful for my question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474936/6934036

variables  that start with HTTP are not reliable