# Is there a way to detect whether the connection comes through CloudFlare?

Tags: php, security

I was wondering if variables with `$ _SERVER` should be treated as safe or whether they should be filtered before use. I am trying to detect if the connection comes from CloudFlare or not. On this basis, I choose the method of obtaining the customer's IP address. When the connection comes from CloudFlare `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]` should be present and its contents should be the IP of the client.

According to [Which $_SERVER variables are safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe) `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]` could be user controlled so IP obtained this way could be spoofed.
`$ip = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])?$ _SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]:$ _SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

Is there any good solution to this problem?

Comment: No, they are not safe.

Comment: Also related https://security.stackexchange.com/a/32488/83382

Answer (score 4):

No data for `$_SERVER` is explicitly designed to be treated as SQL source code.

Some data in `$_SERVER` is directly copied from the HTTP request (i.e. is user input).

It should be treated as any other input from outside the system and appropriate escaping / filtering should be applied.

Comment: And even *if* they were safe, escaping still should be done. Better be safe than sorry.