# Codeigniter 4 .env variables in $_SERVER?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter-4, .env

As part of debugging an application I'm logging the $_SERVER variable to my log table.  I noticed that the custom settings from the .env file are included in the $_SERVER variable, including database credentials.  Is this normal?  Seems like a very bad idea.

For example, the following is included when I get the contents of $_SERVER (data is JSON formatted for logging):

```
...    
"CI_ENVIRONMENT":"production",
"database.default.hostname":"localhost",
"database.default.database":"app",
"database.default.username":"app_user",
"database.default.password":"*REDACTED*",
"database.default.DBDriver":"MySQLi",
...
```

Since this is a server only variable I don't have specific concerns with this I guess, but it was shocking to see the database credentials in the log table where I had no expectation they would end up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation:

> Is this normal? Seems like a very bad idea.

In reference to vanilla PHP and Apache/Nginx web server, you **wouldn't** find `.env` file environment variables in the [`$_SERVER` superglobal variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

However, in the world of CodeIgniter 4, at the time of writing this post, all configured `.env` file environment variables are *copied* to the [`$_ENV`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php) and [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal variables if they don't exist already.

##### Excerpt from [CodeIgniter4/public/index.php](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/f35f956d083eb3872b52af0f578a1a14ba6a471f/public/index.php#L42)

```php
// Load environment settings from .env files into $_SERVER and $_ENV
require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php';
(new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(ROOTPATH))->load();
```

##### Excerpt from [CodeIgniter4/system/Config/DotEnv.php](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/f35f956d083eb3872b52af0f578a1a14ba6a471f/system/Config/DotEnv.php#L93)

```php
    protected function setVariable(string $name, string $value = '')
    {
        if (! getenv($name, true)) {
            putenv("{$name}={$value}");
        }

        if (empty($_ENV[$name])) {
            $_ENV[$name] = $value;
        }

        if (empty($_SERVER[$name])) {
            $_SERVER[$name] = $value;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why `.env` file environment variables were copied to the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable, but I assume it was done for convenience.

As far as security of the contents of the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable, please  refer to [Which $_SERVER variables are safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474936/7376590)

#### Solution

> Since this is a server-only variable I don't have specific concerns
> with this I guess, but it was shocking to see the database credentials
> in the log table where I had no expectation they would end up.

I was also surprised to notice that kind of behavior.
Nonetheless, as a solution to your issue, instead of logging the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable, log the result of this:

```php
array_diff($_SERVER, $_ENV);
```

This will give you an associative array that **doesn't** have `.env` file environment variables.